# multiple attribute in angular-strap directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap's [select](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects#selects).
I have $scope.id in my controller and I want to set multiple attribute to true only when $scope.id is null. So, my code is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default full-width" ng-model="languages"
    data-html="1" multiple="{{!id}}" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-max-length="100" placeholder="Choose..."
    data-ng-options="language.Id as language.FriendlyName for language in languages" bs-select>
Action <span class="caret"></span>
```

But it doesn't work: in all cases the select is in multiple mode.
I've tried other variants that didn't help me too, in all cases the select allows multiple selections:

multiple="{{id}}", data-ng-attr-multiple="!id, data-ng-attr-multiple="{{!id}}

And even

multiple="0", multiple="false"

It seems multiple attribute is used only for setting multiple mode...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the value of `multiple` attribute is only read once on initialization (need to check sources to verifiy it). You can always create two components and show them appropriately:

```
<button ng-if="id" type="button" ng-model="languages" ... bs-select>
<button ng-if="!id" type="button" ng-model="languages" ... bs-select multiple="true">
```

Comment: Yes, I can create 2 components, but it is a bad approach

Comment: Why do you consider it bad? They are two different components. In HTML you also have select and multiple select and can't have both at once.